# best way to speed up multiprocessing code in python?

Tags: python, matrix, multiprocessing, process-pool

I am trying to mess around with matrices in python, and wanted to use multiprocessing to processes each row separately for a math operation, I have posted a minimal reproducible sample below, but keep in mind that for my actual code I do in-fact need the entire matrix passed to the helper function. This sample takes literally forever to process a 10,000 by 10,000 matrix. Almost 2 hours with 9 processes. Looking in task manage it seems only 4-5 of the threads will run at any given time on my cpu, and the application never uses more than 25%. I've done my absolute best to avoid branches in my real code, though the sample provided is branchless. It still takes roughly 25 seconds to process a 1000 by 1000 matrix on my machine, which is ludacris to me as a mainly c++ developer. I wrote serial code in C that executes the entire 10,000 by 10,000 in constant time in less than a second. I think the main bottleneck is the multiprocessing code, but I am required to do this with multiprocessing. Any ideas for how I could go about improving this? Each row can be processed entirely separately but they need to be joined together back into a matrix for my actual code.

```
import random
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time


def addMatrixRow(matrixData):
    matrix = matrixData[0]
    rowNum = matrixData[1]
    del (matrixData)
    rowSum = 0
    for colNum in range(len(matrix[rowNum])):
        rowSum += matrix[rowNum][colNum]

    return rowSum


def genMatrix(row, col):
    matrix = list()
    for i in range(row):
        matrix.append(list())
        for j in range(col):
            matrix[i].append(random.randint(0, 1))
    return matrix

def main():
    matrix = genMatrix(1000, 1000)
    print("generated matrix")
    MAX_PROCESSES = 4
    finalSum = 0

    processPool = Pool(processes=MAX_PROCESSES)
    poolData = list()

    start = time.time()
    for i in range(100):
        for rowNum in range(len(matrix)):
            matrixData = [matrix, rowNum]
            poolData.append(matrixData)

        finalData = processPool.map(addMatrixRow, poolData)
        poolData = list()
        finalSum += sum(finalData)
    end = time.time()
    print(end-start)
    print(f'final sum {finalSum}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Honestly you won't get anywhere in pure Python, there's a reason everyone uses numpy which calls C/C++ code.

Comment: Yeah I'm not supposed to use any libraries for this that aren't included in python itself. If it were up to me I would make my own C bindings to my branchless code and just call that

Comment: If I were you, I'd first try to not use multiprocessing at all and benchmark that first. There's (quite) some overhead with using the `multiprocessing` library and doing some operations like matrix multiplication will probably be faster without that code, nor allocating a bunch of lists.

Comment: Yes the code runs faster in serial almost every time. Multiprocessing is a requirement of this task. It's a very poorly designed assignment in my opinion and I don't know why python of all languages was chosen for this task considering that even with the GIL not being as big a problem for multiprocessing, the code will almost always run slower than if you didn't spawn a process in the first place.

Comment: Yeah this doesn't seem like a good assignment, it'll have you look more into Python though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `matrix` has 1000 rows of 1000 elements each and you are summing each row 100 times. By my calculation, that is 100,000 tasks you are submitting to the pool passing a one-million element matrix each time. Ouch!

Now I know you say that the worker function `addMatrixRow` must have access to the complete matrix. Fine. But instead of passing it a 100,000 times, you can reduce that to 4 times by initializing each process in the pool with a global variable set to the matrix using the *initializer* and *initargs* arguments when you construct the pool. You are able to get away with this because the matrix is read-only.

And instead of creating `poolArgs` as a large list you can instead create a generator function that when iterated returns the next argument to be submitted to the pool. But to take advantage of this you cannot use the `map` method, which will convert the generator to a list and not save you any memory. Instead use `imap_unordered` (rather than `imap` since you do not care now in what order your worker function is returning its results because of the commutative law of addition). But with such a large input, you should be using the *chunksize* argument with `imap_unordered`. So that the number of reads and writes to the pool's task queue is greatly reduced(albeit the size of the data being written is larger for each queue operation).

If all of this is somewhat vague to you, I suggest reading the docs thoroughly for class `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` and its `imap` and `imap_unordered` methods.

I have made a few other optimizations replacing `for` loops with list comprehensions and using the built-in `sum` function.

```py
import random
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time


def init_pool_processes(m):
    global matrix
    matrix = m 

def addMatrixRow(rowNum):
    return sum(matrix[rowNum])

def genMatrix(row, col):
    return [[random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(col)] for _ in range(row)]
   
def compute_chunksize(pool_size, iterable_size):
    chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size)
    if remainder:
        chunksize += 1
    return chunksize

def main():
    matrix = genMatrix(1000, 1000)
    print("generated matrix")
    MAX_PROCESSES = 4

    processPool = Pool(processes=MAX_PROCESSES, initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(matrix,))
    start = time.time()
    # Use a generator function:
    poolData = (rowNum for _ in range(100) for rowNum in range(len(matrix)))
    # Compute efficient chunksize
    chunksize = compute_chunksize(MAX_PROCESSES, len(matrix) * 100)
    finalSum = sum(processPool.imap_unordered(addMatrixRow, poolData, chunksize=chunksize))
    end = time.time()
    print(end-start)
    print(f'final sum {finalSum}')
    processPool.close()
    processPool.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```py
generated matrix
0.35799622535705566
final sum 49945400
```

**Note the running time of .36 seconds.**

Assuming you have more CPU cores (than 4), use them all for an even greater reduction in time.

Comment: Some of this doesn't apply to the assignment I had ( I didn't want to post the code to it out of fear of someone else copying me ) but using these ideas I was able to get the runtime of my code way down. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

you are serializing the entire matrix on each function call, you should only send the data that you are processing to the function, nothing more ... and python has a built-in `sum` function that has a very optimized C code.

```py
import random
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time


def addMatrixRow(row_data):
    rowSum = sum(row_data)
    return rowSum


def genMatrix(row, col):
    matrix = list()
    for i in range(row):
        matrix.append(list())
        for j in range(col):
            matrix[i].append(random.randint(0, 1))
    return matrix

def main():
    matrix = genMatrix(1000, 1000)
    print("generated matrix")
    MAX_PROCESSES = 4
    finalSum = 0

    processPool = Pool(processes=MAX_PROCESSES)
    poolData = list()

    start = time.time()
    for i in range(100):
        for rowNum in range(len(matrix)):
            matrixData = matrix[rowNum]
            poolData.append(matrixData)

        finalData = processPool.map(addMatrixRow, poolData)
        poolData = list()
        finalSum += sum(finalData)
    end = time.time()
    print(end-start)
    print(f'final sum {finalSum}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
generated matrix
3.5028157234191895
final sum 49963400
```

just not using `process pool` and running the code serially using `list(map(sum,poolData))`

```
generated matrix
1.2143816947937012
final sum 50020800
```

so yeh python can do it in a second.

Comment: Yes I know that both of those are some of the main causes of inefficiency but they are requirements for the assignment I am trying to do. I need the entire matrix to get wrap-around neighbors of cells, and I am required to do it with multiprocessing despite serial always being faster. (and not using map at all being even faster than that) I am just looking for ways to improve the default efficiency of process pool maps though I will try to refactor my actual code to pass around the entire matrix less